# How to access the current table in Numbers?

Tags: python, iwork, sourceforge-appscript, py-appscript

How do I access the current table in Numbers using `py-appscript`?

---

For posterity, the program I created using this information clears all the cells of the current table and returns the selection to cell `A1`. I turned it into a Service using a python Run Shell Script in Automator and attached it to Numbers.

```
 from appscript import *

 Numbers = app('Numbers')
 current_table = None
 for sheet in Numbers.documents.first.sheets():
      for table in sheet.tables():
           if table.selection_range():
                current_table = table

 if current_table:
      for cell in current_table.cells():
           cell.value.set('')

      current_table.selection_range.set(to=current_table.ranges[u'A1'])
```

It was used to clear large tables of numbers that I used for temporary calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> d = app('Numbers').documents.first()  # reference to current top document
```

EDIT: There doesn't seem to be a straight-forward single reference to the current table but it looks like you can find it by searching the current first document's sheets for a table with a non-null selection_range, so something like this:

```
>>> nu = app('Numbers')
>>> for sheet in nu.documents.first.sheets():
...   for table in sheet.tables():
...     if table.selection_range():
...        print table.name()
```

Comment: This actually isn't working for me. It returns the first table in the sheet, not the currently selected table.

Comment: Ironically, I *just* came to this conclusion myself and was about to post it :) The syntax in your solution is cleaner, though.

Comment: Heh. The wonders of Apple Event scriptable apps: seek and ye shall find.  And there is seldom the one obvious way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've got another question on appscript that I'm hoping you have the answer to.